# Discord JS Player / Problem with players stream and state

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots, audio-streaming, audio-player

i've been working for a while on a discord music bot,
been doing good so far but i've encountered some issue.
after realising that ytld-core was not streaming sound properly to the in-uilt discord player, i've switched to play-dl
The problem is that whenever i start playing an audio, the state of the player stays on : Buffering
even tho i can listen to the while song through the bot.
while going for a listener on player's switching state :

```
        player.on('stateChange', (oldState, newState) => {
            console.log(oldState.status, newState.status);
        });
```

it goes from "Buffering" to :
Playing (old status) to Idle (immediatly after) when the song is finished.
even if it's actually playing sound, the issue is that i can't use Pause, unpause and stop methods of the player.

here's the code (im' new to it, don't mind the mess please) :

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, hideLinkEmbed } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { createAudioPlayer, NoSubscriberBehavior, joinVoiceChannel, createAudioResource, subscribe, VoiceConnectionStatus } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const ConfigJSON = require('../config.json');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const playdl = require('play-dl');
const ytsr = require('ytsr');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');



module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('music')
        .setDescription('Play a song in a voice channel')
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName('play')
                .setDescription('Play a song in a voice channel')
                .addStringOption(option =>
                    option.setName('query')
                        .setDescription('The song you want to play')
                        .setRequired(true)))
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName('pause')
                .setDescription('Stop the music and leave the voice channel'))
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName('resume')
                .setDescription('Resume the music in the voice channel'))
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName('stop')
                .setDescription('Stop the music and leave the voice channel')),


    async execute(interaction) {

        const subcommand = interaction.options.getSubcommand();


        const YTapiKey = ConfigJSON.YoutubeAPIKey;

        const player = new createAudioPlayer(
            {
                behaviors: {
                    noSubscriber: NoSubscriberBehavior.Play,
                },
            }
        );

        if (subcommand === 'play') {

            interaction.deferReply();
            const query = interaction.options.getString('query');


            const opts = {
                maxResults: 1,
                key: YTapiKey,

            }



            const queryResult = await ytsr(query);
            const Finalquery = String( await queryResult.items[0].url);
            const streamplay = await playdl.stream(Finalquery);
            const connection = new joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: interaction.member.voice.channel.id,
                guildId: interaction.guild.id,
                adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
                selfDeaf: true,
                selfMute: false,
            });

            connection.subscribe(player);
            const resource = createAudioResource(streamplay.stream, { inputType: streamplay.type });

            let embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle(queryResult.items[0].title)
                .setURL(queryResult.items[0].url)
                .setThumbnail(String(queryResult.items[0].bestThumbnail.url))
                .setDescription("Currently playing ....")
                .setFooter({text:"Requested by " + interaction.user.username, iconURL:interaction.user.avatarURL()})
                .setTimestamp()
                .setColor(0x00AE86)

            player.play(resource);
            await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed] });
            console
        }

        if (subcommand === 'pause') {
            console.log("pause");
            console.log(player);
            await player.pause();
            player.on('error', (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
        if (subcommand === 'resume') {
            console.log("resume");
            console.log(player.state.status);
        }
        if (subcommand === 'stop') {
            console.log("stop");
            console.log(player.state.status);
        }
        player.on('stateChange', (oldState, newState) => {
            console.log(oldState.status, newState.status);
        });
    }   
}
```

i've tried reorganizing the code, making functions, awaiting some elements to make a proper flow.. but i can"t seem to find a proper way to build this.

Comment: I don't understand, is the only issue that the status of the bot is not correct?

Comment: Yes because whenever i try to use other methods like "pause" or "stop", thet state of the player changes to the right status, but there's no action from the bot.
when i do player.pause(), the state changes to pause, but the player keeps streaming, same goes with stop and disconnect